# Fundamental group in flat families

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Suppose I have a flat family $\pi: \mathscr X \to S$ of schemes over $\mathbb C$, all embedded in some common $\mathbb P^n$. Then we can regard the elements of this family as complex spaces, and in particular they are topological spaces in the classical topology.

Suppose that a special fiber of $X_0 = \pi^{-1}(0)$ of the family has trivial fundamental group $\pi_1(X_0)=\{e \}$. $X_0$ may be singular.

Can we say anything about the fundamental group of nearby fibers? Are they also trivial?

**Added:** For example, is the size of fundamental group semi-continous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the fibres are all smooth, then by Ehresmann Theorem they are diffeomorphic, in particularly homotopically equivalent and so the answer is *yes*.

Instead, if you allow singular fibres the answer is in general *no*. Think of a flat family $\mathscr{X}_t$  of smooth, plane cubic curves degenerating to a cuspidal curve $X_0$. Then $X_0$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$, in particular it is simply connected, whereas $\pi_1(X_t)\simeq\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, could it for example hold that the size of the fundamental group is semi-continous in flat families? (as is true for $h^0(X,\mathscr O_X)$ (in the sense that the size can only drop outside special points)

Comment: In my example, the fundamental group is trivial at the special point and infinite outside, so the answer is clearly *no* in general (by the way, what is the "size" of an infinite group? Maybe you mean the rank, at least in the abelian case?) Or am I misunderstanding your question?